# Regular expressions and divisibility

Tags: php, regex

How can I create a regular expression which test if a number is divisible by i (2<=i<=10), 8 expressions in total? One can only assume that integers are positive. You can use symbols [] and [^] , ?, * and + , | and (). PHP's ereg-function should accept it.

Comment: Why regex? Why not just divide the number? Regular expressions are not the right tool for that.

Comment: I hate interviews like these. Regex should not be used like this.  I can cook eggs on my radiator but doing so would be a poor use of my radiator.

Comment: *sniff sniff* I smell homework.  And bad homework at that.

Comment: You don't want to work for someone who thinks a regular expression is the right tool for this job.

Comment: I think I won't get the job. Maybe the interviewer wanted to ask a hard question to find out who knows also some special things. I had no idea how to construct those expressions.

Comment: @amateurprogrammer: I wouldn't want such a job anyway. There is no point in asking how to solve a certain problem with the wrong tool. You should answer: This problem should not be solved with regular expressions.

Comment: It could have been a trick question.  Maybe the answer they were looking for was "I would never use regex to do this."

Comment: I have an impression that you're not entirely understand how works the regular expressions.

Comment: It's true that I haven't very much experience on reqexps. I was thinking whether one can write a finite automata and convert it to regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this is a homework problem there is no reason to use regular expressions in this case.

Use the modulus operator, it gives you the remainder of the value divided by.

```
if($number%$i) { "This runs if $number modulus is not 0 (not evenly divisible by $i)" }
else { "This runs if $number modulus is 0 ( evenly Divisible by $i)" }
```

**Edit:**  Oh it's an *interview question*.  Yes, the correct answer here is "That is not the correct tool for this problem!"

Comment: @Alok has the correct solution below.  Regex -> finite state machine.

Answer (score 1):

@Charles answer in his comment is incorrect. Here is how you build a regex for divisbility by 3: http://alokmenghrajani.github.com/triple/. You can do something similar for 7.

Comment: This is totally the correct answer.  Thank you, Alok.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you translate the number to unary (`1` = `1`, `2` = `11`, `3` = `111`, `4` = `1111` etc).

Then you can check whether your number matches `^(1{divisor})*$`. If you can't use `{}`, you need to spell it out. So to check divisibility by 4, try to match `^(1111)*$`, etc.

Nobody in their right mind would do it that way, though. And if your interviewer asks you to use `ereg`, then his regex knowledge is a few decades old, I guess.

Comment: I think I need first a reqexp to convert 4_10 to 1111_2. A general converter might be hard to do.

Comment: @amateurprogrammer: That is definitely impossible using regex. But checking for divisors using regex in base 10 is also impossible.

Comment: @Tim, it is possible for some specific integers, like 2, 5, 10. But that's probably not what the interviewer expects.

Comment: @Michał: Right, and for 4 and 8, too (although the latter would make for a horrible regex). No way for 3, 6, 7 and 9, though.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Actually it is possible for any number in any base.  3 is easy: the regex for matching multiples of 3 that contain only 0, 1, and 2 is `/^(0|10*2|10*10*1|20*1)+$/` and you can transform this into a regex to match any multiple of 3 by replacing 0 with `[0369]`, 1 with `[147]`, and 2 with `[258]`.  The expression for 7 is long and complicated (in base 10, since 7 does not divide a power of (10-1)*10), but it does exist.

Comment: @Charles: Very clever. I stand corrected, and I would love to see the divisible-by-7 regex. Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: It's hard enough to make this short that I asked for a decent solution on codegolf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3503/2605 .  I'll post a solution there next week if I get a chance.

Comment: There is some kind of reg. exp tester in a Finnish forum Ohjelmointiputka. It says that 27103396048530387964483 is divisible by 7 by the expression given by Griffin won't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So, obviously you wouldn't use a regular expression for this normally... but people do crazy things. There's a regular expression out there to determine if a number is prime...

As a thought on how to go about a solution, if you're allowed to represent the number in another format...

- Convert the number to a string with a number of 1s equal to the size of the number (4 = "1111")
- regexp `/^(1{$divisor})+$/`

As a sample in Tcl

```
proc testit {value} {
    set value1 [string repeat 1 $value]
    for {set i 2} {$i <= 10} {incr i} {
        set matches [regexp "^(1{$i})+$" $value1]
        puts "${i}: $matches"
    }
}
```

Since you can't use the `{}` construct, you can replace the `1{$i}` with a number of ones equal to i.

Comment: No regular expression can determine if a string is the decimal representation of a prime.  It's not hard to make one that matches the unary representation of primes (and easy to make one that matches the unary representation of composites).